# Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal con jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar

Tengo un proyecto spring-boot el cual he empaquetado en un jar. Pero cuando trato de lanzarlo me da un error:

```
java -cp .\timer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar es.company.timer.TimerApplication
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal
```

Entonces para ver la ruta he descomprimido el jar con el WinRar y me dado cuenta que la ruta de la clase principal es tal y como la puse arriba sumado que tiene dos directorios mas:

- BOOT-INF

  - classes

He añadido al comando delante de la declaracion del package("es.company...") BOOT-INF.classes.es.company y el error persiste. Googleando he encontrado que las versiones superiores de la 1.4 de spring boot ahora mete todo en ese directorio

He hecho lo siguiente:

- Cambiar la version de spring-boot a la 1.3.x.RELEASE
- Añadir la main class en el pom

Y el error persiste. Mi pregunta es a día de hoy y con esta nueva versión de spring boot, como puedo ejecutar esa clase que se encuentra debajo de BOOT-INF desde la consola. ¿Como seria la sentnecia?

Comment: No sé como has creado el jar, pero generalmente basta con el comando `java -jar <path_del_jar>`

Comment: El jar le he generado de la siguiene forma :  mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package

Comment: Entonces debería bastarte con la opción -jar... ¿qué hace -cp? No encuentro nada sobre esa opción

Comment: Con el comando java -jar me aparece lo siguiente: Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal your.main.class

Comment: Especifica la clase a ejecutar donde le añadía la clase main: https://www.cbronline.com/what-is/what-is-java-cp-4926798/

Comment: Estoy torpe, ya veo que cp es classpath

Comment: El *jar* no debería incluirte los dos directorios iniciales, debería empezar por el paquete base (es decir, al abrir el jar con un visor de zips debería mostrarte solo la carpeta "es" e hijas). Y yo uso *mvn package* habitualmente y no hay problemas, mira dentro de *target/classes* a ver qué tienes allí

Comment: Claro en otros jar generados lo tengo asi. Pero ahora me llegado un jar el cual tiene una version de spring-boot superior a la 1.4.1 (sino recuerdo mal a aprtir de esa version spring boot mete las clases del proyecto dentro de esa carpeta). Pero el problema es que hasta el momento no hevisto en internat como lanzar un jar de sa forma

Comment: En target classes tengo la capreta es. y toda la jerarquia esperada de packages

Comment: Pero en el jar la tiene pero dentro de las dos capetas que comentaba

Comment: Con Spring boot 2.1.5 el comando `mvn package && java -jar ...` funciona sin problemas... será algo del pom.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer un jar ejecutable debes indicar en el manifesto la clase que será el punto de entrada (Entry-Point):

En manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: tu.paquete.ClaseConMain
```

Con Maven, en pom.xml:

```
...
<archive>
   <manifest>
      <mainClass>tu.paquete.ClaseConMain</mainClass>
   </manifest>
</archive>
...
```

Imagina que eres la JVM. Te dan un classpath con X jars que contienen Y clases, distribuidas en Z paquetes distintos. Y te dicen: Ejecuta el main de ésta clase, considerando que clases de un mismo paquete se pueden encontrar en jars distintos y que cada clase puede tener un método main. A menos que recorras toda la jerarquía de paquetes hasta encontrar la clase a ejecutar es de mucha ayuda saber que en un -archivo- manifesto en cada jar puedes saber si ahí se encuentra el Entry-Point especificado en la línea de comandos.

En el caso de spring-boot el Entry-Point es delegado:

En manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: tu.paquete.ClaseConMain
```

ó en pom.xml

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
      <configuration>    
         <mainClass>tu.paquete.ClaseConMain</mainClass>
         ...
```