# "no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar" al ejecutar jar en docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

No estoy pudiendo ejecutar un jar de una aplicación Spring-boot en un contenedor.

El archivo Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/demo.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app1.jar
CMD ["java -jar","/app1.jar"]
```

El pom.xml:

```
          ...

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java.version}</maven.compiler.release>        
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

          ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

          ...

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                <release>${java.version}</release>  
                <target>${java.version}</target>  
                 <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <mainClass>com.automotora.rest.AutomotoraApplication</mainClass>          
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>                    
                </configuration>    
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>       
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Notar que si bien llamé al jar en el Dockerfile *app1.jar* el mensaje de error devuelve *app.jar* ¿esto es correcto?

> no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar

La imagen se crea. Pero al correr un contenedor devuelve ese mensaje.

Si ejecuto el jar sin docker usando en la consola:

> java -jar demo.jar

Funciona correctamente

Aquí está el pom.xml completo:
https://github.com/mathiasuy/Automotora/blob/master/pom.xml

Aquí el Dockerfile:
https://github.com/mathiasuy/Automotora/blob/master/Dockerfile

Aquí el resto del código fuente:
https://github.com/mathiasuy/Automotora

Actualización:

Este es el archivo MANIFEST.MF que está dentro del jar:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
>
> Built-By: root
>
> Start-Class: com.automotora.rest.AutomotoraApplication
>
> Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
>
> Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
>
> Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.5.RELEASE
>
> Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
>
> Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_232
>
> Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270070/error-no-se-ha-encontrado-o-cargado-la-clase-principal-con-jar/270104#270104) comento algo para Spring-boot.

Comment: Lo que sugiere esa respuesta ya lo hice, pero el problema sigue. Faltó aclarar que el problema sucede cuando lo ejecuto dentro de un docker, si lo hago desde la consola de Windows ejecuta bien

Comment: Te recomiendo que abras el JAR generado por Maven con WinRAR, o similar. Luego busca en el MANIFEST.MF comprueba que contiene las entradas Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher Start-Class: com.automotora.rest.AutomotoraApplication

Comment: Tiene las 2 entradas. Actualizo la pregunta con esa info

Comment: Si el problema es con Docker intenta con : `CMD ["java","-jar","app1.jar"]`

Comment: No se exactamente si fue esto último lo que lo solucionó pero quedó andando finalmente. Gracias